# Why does this query work?

Tags: oracle, select, subquery

I have two tables, table_a (id, name) and table_b (id), let's say on Oracle 12c.

Why does this query not return an exception?

```
select * from table_a where name in (select name from table_b);
```

From what I understand, Oracle sees this as

```
select * from table_a where name = name;
```

But what I don't get is why?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The query is syntactically correct SQL even if `table_b` does not have a `name` column. The reason is scope resolution.

When the query is parsed, it is first checked whether `table_b` has a `name` column. Since it doesn't, then `table_a` is checked. It would throw an error only if neither of the tables had a `name` column.

Finally the query is executed as:

```
select a.* 
from table_a  a
where a.name in (select a.name 
                 from table_b  b
                );
```

---

As for the results the query would give, for every row of `table_a`, the subquery `(select name from table_b)` - or `(select a.name from table_b  b)` - is a table with a single column with the same `a.name` value and as many rows as `table_b`. So, if `table_b` has 1 or more rows, the query runs as:

```
select a.* 
from table_a  a
where a.name in (a.name, a.name, ..., a.name) ;
```

or:

```
select a.* 
from table_a  a
where a.name = a.name ;
```

or:

```
select a.* 
from table_a  a
where a.name is not null ;
```

If `table_b` is empty, the query will return no rows (thnx to @ughai for pointing that possibility).

---

That (the fact that you don't get an error) is probably the best reason that all column references should be prefixed with the table name/alias. If the query was:

```
select a.* from table_a where a.name in (select b.name from table_b);
```

you would have got the error straight away. When table prefixes are omitted, it is not difficult for such mistakes to happen, especially in more complex queries, and even more important, go unnoticed.

Read also in [Oracle docs: Resolution of Names in Static SQL Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS99882) the similar example B-6 in **Inner capture** and the recommendations in the **Avoiding Inner Capture in SELECT and DML Statements** paragraphs:

> Qualify each column reference in the statement with the appropriate table alias.

Comment: How did you dissect the inner workings of the SQL engine so accurately?

Answer (score 7):

Because

> Oracle performs a correlated subquery when a nested subquery
>   references a column from a table referred to a parent statement one
>   level above the subquery.
>   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357

It means in order to determine whether subquery is correlated Oracle *must* try to resolve names in subquery including outer statement context too. And for unprefixed `name` it's the only resolution possible.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `name` field in `table_b` so Oracle takes the one from `table_a`. I tried the `EXPLAIN PLAN` but this gave me only that there is a `TABLE ACCESS` `FULL`. I presume that this will generate some kind of Cartesian Product between both tables that result in a list of all the names in `table_a` is returned by the sub-query.

Comment: *"There is no name field in table_b so Oracle takes the one from table_a."* Correct. *"I presume that this will generate some kind of Cartesian Product."* Wrong. The query has `from table_a where ...`. It will return all rows from `table_a` except those that `name` is null.

Comment: `TABLE ACCESS FULL` is just Oracle's way of telling you it's doing a sequential scan.

Comment: Your PLAN is irrelevant - there may well be indexing with huge tables - I'm assuming that your running on test data?